# Relation between the white noise and the Brownian motion.

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am confused about the relation between the white noise and Brownian motion.

The white nose $W(t)$ is formally regarded as the derivative of a Brownian motion B(t), i.e. $W(t) = dB(t)/dt$. However, the Brownian motion $B(t)$ is nowhere differentiable.

Is there any interpretation for these conflicting statements.

Comment: Nowhere differentiable locally bounded functions are locally integrable and therefore have distributional derivatives

Comment: A question after almost 9 years!
Does it mean that the writing  SDE
$$
dX(t) = \mu dt + \sigma dB(t),
$$
is not mathematically correct?